# Face clustering using Chinese Whispers algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, dlib

I am trying to use Chinese whispers algorithm for face clustering. I have used dlib and python for extracting features for each face and mapped into 128 D vector as described by Davisking at https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/dnn_face_recognition_ex.cpp.

Then I constructed a graph following the instructions given there. I implemented Chinese whispers algorithm and applied to this graph.  Can anyone tell me what mistake I have done? Can anyone upload python code for face clustering using chinese whispers algorithm? Here is my code of chinese whispers :

```
import networkx as nx
import random
from random import shuffle
import math
def chinese_whispers(nodes,edges,iterations):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    #print(G.node)
    for n, v in enumerate(nodes):
        G.node[n]['class'] = v
        #print(n,v)
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    #gn=G.nodes()
    #for node in gn:
    #print((node,G[node],G.node,G.node[node]))
    #(0, {16: {'weight': 0.49846761956907698}, 14: {'weight': 0.55778036559581601}, 7: {'weight': 0.43902511314524784}}, {'class': 0})
    for z in range(0, iterations):
        gn = G.nodes()
    # I randomize the nodes to give me an arbitrary start point
        shuffle(gn)
        for node in gn:
            neighs = G[node]
            classes = {}
       # do an inventory of the given nodes neighbours and edge weights
            for ne in neighs:
                if isinstance(ne, int):
                    key=G.node[ne]['class']
                    if key in classes:
                        classes[key] += G[node][ne]['weight']
                    else:
                        classes[key] = G[node][ne]['weight']
       # find the class with the highest edge weight sum

            max = 0
            maxclass = 0
            for c in classes:
                if classes[c] > max:
                    max = classes[c]
                    maxclass = c
       # set the class of target node to the winning local class
            G.node[node]['class'] = maxclass

    n_clusters = []
    for node in G.nodes():
        n_clusters.append(G.node[node]['class'])
    return(n_clusters)
```

Here is the code of facial feature extraction and encoding of each faces in 128 D vector and from these construction of graph for applying chinese whispers.

```
from sklearn import cluster
import cv2
import sys
import os
import dlib
import glob
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import chinese
from chinese import chinese_whispers
predictor_path = "/home/deeplearning/Desktop/face_recognition 
examples/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
face_rec_model_path = "/home/deeplearning/Desktop/face_recognition 
examples/dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat"
faces_folder_path = "/home/deeplearning/Desktop/face_recognition 
examples/test11/"

# Load all the models we need: a detector to find the faces, a shape predictor
# to find face landmarks so we can precisely localize the face, and finally the
# face recognition model.
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
#print (detector)
sp = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
facerec = dlib.face_recognition_model_v1(face_rec_model_path)

#win = dlib.image_window()

# Now process all the images
dict={}
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.jpg")):
    print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    img = io.imread(f)
    dets = detector(img, 3)
    for k, d in enumerate(dets):
        shape = sp(img, d)
        face_descriptor = facerec.compute_face_descriptor(img, shape)
        a=np.array(face_descriptor)
        dict[(f,d)] = (a,f)



answ=np.array(list(dict.values()))
tmp=answ.shape[0]
ans=np.zeros((tmp,128))
for i in range(tmp):
    ans[i]=np.array(answ[i][0])
nodes=[]
for i in range(tmp):
    nodes.append(i)
edges=[]
for i in range(tmp):
    for j in range(i+1,tmp):
        dist=np.sqrt(np.sum((ans[i]-ans[j])**2))
        if dist < 0.6:
            edges.append((i,j,{'weight': dist}))


iterations=10
cluster=chinese_whispers(nodes,edges,iterations)
```

I don't understand what wrong I am doing.Can anyone help me about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: "But I did not get good accuracy" isn't a very helpful problem description. Stack overflow is best used for solving specific problems, and this sort of question

Answer (score 3):

I've used *Dlib* for face clustering before.

I'm sorry I did not get your question correctly. 
Are you getting an error or you aren't getting an accurate result?

Assuming that you are not getting proper result, I would suggest using [shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat](http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat.bz2) instead of *64* face landmarks as it gives better result when clustering using Chinese whispers algorithm.

You can also try out DLib's own Chinese whispers clustering function and see if it works better.

Example - [face_clustering.py](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/python_examples/face_clustering.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# The contents of this file are in the public domain. See LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt
#
#   This example shows how to use dlib's face recognition tool for clustering using chinese_whispers.
#   This is useful when you have a collection of photographs which you know are linked to
#   a particular person, but the person may be photographed with multiple other people.
#   In this example, we assume the largest cluster will contain photos of the common person in the
#   collection of photographs. Then, we save extracted images of the face in the largest cluster in
#   a 150x150 px format which is suitable for jittering and loading to perform metric learning (as shown
#   in the dnn_metric_learning_on_images_ex.cpp example.
#   https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/dnn_metric_learning_on_images_ex.cpp
#
# COMPILING/INSTALLING THE DLIB PYTHON INTERFACE
#   You can install dlib using the command:
#       pip install dlib
#
#   Alternatively, if you want to compile dlib yourself then go into the dlib
#   root folder and run:
#       python setup.py install
#
#   Compiling dlib should work on any operating system so long as you have
#   CMake installed.  On Ubuntu, this can be done easily by running the
#   command:
#       sudo apt-get install cmake
#
#   Also note that this example requires Numpy which can be installed
#   via the command:
#       pip install numpy

import sys
import os
import dlib
import glob

if len(sys.argv) != 5:
    print(
        "Call this program like this:\n"
        "   ./face_clustering.py shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat ../examples/faces output_folder\n"
        "You can download a trained facial shape predictor and recognition model from:\n"
        "    http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat.bz2\n"
        "    http://dlib.net/files/dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat.bz2")
    exit()

predictor_path = sys.argv[1]
face_rec_model_path = sys.argv[2]
faces_folder_path = sys.argv[3]
output_folder_path = sys.argv[4]

# Load all the models we need: a detector to find the faces, a shape predictor
# to find face landmarks so we can precisely localize the face, and finally the
# face recognition model.
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
sp = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
facerec = dlib.face_recognition_model_v1(face_rec_model_path)

descriptors = []
images = []

# Now find all the faces and compute 128D face descriptors for each face.
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.jpg")):
    print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    img = dlib.load_rgb_image(f)

    # Ask the detector to find the bounding boxes of each face. The 1 in the
    # second argument indicates that we should upsample the image 1 time. This
    # will make everything bigger and allow us to detect more faces.
    dets = detector(img, 1)
    print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(dets)))

    # Now process each face we found.
    for k, d in enumerate(dets):
        # Get the landmarks/parts for the face in box d.
        shape = sp(img, d)

        # Compute the 128D vector that describes the face in img identified by
        # shape.  
        face_descriptor = facerec.compute_face_descriptor(img, shape)
        descriptors.append(face_descriptor)
        images.append((img, shape))

# Now let's cluster the faces.  
labels = dlib.chinese_whispers_clustering(descriptors, 0.5)
num_classes = len(set(labels))
print("Number of clusters: {}".format(num_classes))

# Find biggest class
biggest_class = None
biggest_class_length = 0
for i in range(0, num_classes):
    class_length = len([label for label in labels if label == i])
    if class_length > biggest_class_length:
        biggest_class_length = class_length
        biggest_class = i

print("Biggest cluster id number: {}".format(biggest_class))
print("Number of faces in biggest cluster: {}".format(biggest_class_length))

# Find the indices for the biggest class
indices = []
for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    if label == biggest_class:
        indices.append(i)

print("Indices of images in the biggest cluster: {}".format(str(indices)))

# Ensure output directory exists
if not os.path.isdir(output_folder_path):
    os.makedirs(output_folder_path)

# Save the extracted faces
print("Saving faces in largest cluster to output folder...")
for i, index in enumerate(indices):
    img, shape = images[index]
    file_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, "face_" + str(i))
    # The size and padding arguments are optional with default size=150x150 and padding=0.25
    dlib.save_face_chip(img, shape, file_path, size=150, padding=0.25)
```

You can also change the threshold value and iterations to see if it gives you a better result.

Hope this helps.